# Should return upfront_fare_required error in sandbox

Tags: uber-api

Sandbox is not behaving as in production regarding products requiring upfront fare pricing.

In production, requesting for such product will return error with `status=422` and `code=upfront_fare_required`, which is expected behavior. By the way, this error code should be added to API docs. (Currently not listed in https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/requests-post#http-error-codes)

But most importantly, sandbox should behave like production environment and return an error if no `fare_id` is provided when requesting a product that requires upfront fare pricing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for pointing out to this inconsistency between sandbox and production environment. We confirmed behaviour you described in your post - and we will consider fixing sandbox behaviour in the future - there is no timeline when this will be done.